# Looking for the name of a part

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm looking for a name of a part. It looks like a cable inside another cable. The idea is that you can just pull on the inside cable and get the force at the other end. You can just attach the outside cable somewhere, and don't have to bother about pulleys and such.

Does this exists, and what is it called?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a schematic or sketch. I'm having trouble visualizing this.

Comment: I rolled the title back because the edit invalidates the answer by @Corey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a **Bowden cable.** See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowden_cable

As @Corey said, they are often used for bike brake cables, but they have many other uses as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your talking about bicycle cable and housing. Search for "brake cable"

There are also different types of these cables for different applications. Teflon lined inner for smoother operations, stainless for corrosion resistance, linear wound, opposed to radially, outer housings that can withstand turning/mild kinking without tightening the inner cable, etc.

Comment: Indeed what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One name is “Bowden cable”, which is the inner cable and outer sheath / cover providing a force by the movement of one relative to the other - usually the inner moves relative to the outer...

Comment: Indeed what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also known as a "Push-Pull Cable" or "(mechanical) Control Cable"